# Unable to return nil in generic function

Tags: swift, generics, option-type

I am trying to understand generics better and am writing a function, that finds a key in a given dictionary with a given value. 
If the value is not found it should return nil.

```
func findKey<Key, Value: Equatable>(for value: Value, in dictionary: [Key: Value]) -> Key {
    for set in dictionary {
        if set.value == value {
            return set.key
        }
    }
    return nil //ERROR: Nil is incompatible with Type 'Key'
}
```

I reveice this error:

> Nil is incompatible with Type 'Key'

Comment: It's worth it to read the section about **Optionals** in the [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330)

Comment: @vadian It's worth it to read the s̶e̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶a̶b̶o̶u̶t̶ ̶O̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶a̶l̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to return nil you need to return a Key Optional " `Key?` "

You can read more about optionals [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330).

```
func findKey<Key, Value: Equatable>(for value: Value, in dictionary: [Key: Value]) -> Key? {
   for set in dictionary {
       if set.value == value {
           return set.key
       }
   }
   return nil  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is set to return a `Key` as indicated by `-> Key`

You cannot return a nil because `Key` is an unwrapped variable. Instead, you can set the function to return an `Optional` which means that it can either have a `Key`, or it can be nil. Simply add a `?` after the return type

```
func findKey<Key, Value: Equatable>(for value: Value, in dictionary: [Key: Value]) -> Key? {
    for set in dictionary {
        if set.value == value {
            return set.key
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative implementation:

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {
    func key(forValue v: Value) -> Key? {
        return self.first(where: { $0.value == v})?.key
    } 
}

["a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3].key(forValue: 3) // => Optional("c")
```

Note that in the case where two `Key`s map to the same `Value` `v`, it's not deterministic which of the two `Key`s will be returned. To get all `Key`s mapping the `Value` `v`, you can do this:

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {
    func keys(forValue v: Value) -> [Key] {
        return self.filter{ $0.value == v}.map{ $0.key }
    } 
}

["a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 3].keys(forValue: 3) // => ["d", "c"]
```